# Private using declaration of base constructor is not private

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, using-declaration

The `using` declaration for the base constructor is private, but the class can still be constructed. Why?

Accessibility works differently for the `operator[]`'s `using` declaration which must be public.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Vec : std::vector<T>
{
private:
    using std::vector<T>::vector;       // Works, even if private. Why?
public:
    using std::vector<T>::operator[];   // must be public
};

int main(){
    Vec<int> vec = {2, 2};
    auto test = vec[1];
}
```

What if I wanted the constructor to be private? Could it be done with a `using` declaration?

Comment: @RemyLebeau And the compiler generated constructor takes an initializer list?

Comment: I have to say I am mystified by the down-vote. This is a good question, [mcve] and all.

Comment: Maybe lack of research effort because cppr explains it in plain English @juanchopanza? Anyway, not much use in discussing it I suppose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using-declarations for base class constructors keep the same accessibility as the base class, regardless of the accessibility of the base class. From [[namespace.udecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#19):

> A synonym created by a using-declaration has the usual accessibility for a member-declaration. A using-declarator that names a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, *the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class*, and **the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored**

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

In plain English, [from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors):

> It has the same access as the corresponding base constructor.

If you want the "inherited" constructors to be private, you have to manually specify the constructors. You cannot do this with a using-declaration.

Comment: Alright but this implies that access to base constructor taking initializer list is `public`. Note that base class access in this example is actually `private`.

Comment: It will worth adding the first line of that paragraph from the standard. It explains why `using std::vector<T>::operator[];` needs to be in `public` section.

Comment: The question was actually about keeping inherited constructor private. It seems that with this fancy rule it would be impossible to achieve this with just `using` declaration. Or alter access in general.

Comment: *"the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class"* shouldn't they be inaccessible because the entire base class is inaccessible on the first place? I seems that this part is actually interpreted "regardless of the access specifier used for inheritance".

Answer (score 3):

[`using` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) states that an inherited constructor

> has the same access as the corresponding base constructor.

It further gives some hint on the rationale behind this:

> It is `constexpr` if the user-defined constructor would have satisfied `constexpr` constructor requirements. It is deleted if the corresponding base constructor is deleted or if a defaulted default constructor would be deleted

Apparently, you cannot explicitly `constexpr` or `delete` an inherited constructor, so those characteristics are simply inherited. Same goes for access levels.